# Поддержка jQuery на iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery, html

Подскажите, как обстоят дела с Javascript и jQuery? Будут ли работать простые функции. И сработают ли события у тегов типа onclick?

Больше интересуют конструкции типа:

```
to = $('#move').val();
```

т.к. старался не делать ничего сверхъестественного на jQuery.

И загрузить фото с айпада выходит тоже нельзя( через инпут фаил

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит не от IPad, а от браузера на этом IPad! Я проверял свой сайт на Ipad в Safari, все функции работали без проблем, правда немного "подтормаживала" вся анимация. И файлы можно грузить, все можно, все зависит от браузера. Все элементы HTML поддерживаются даже мобильным браузером в телефонах NOKIA.

Comment: Подтверждаю, apple safari на iPhone и iPad адекватно воспринимает js и даже выполняются ajax запросы